# Coordinates and graph

Tags: plotting, graphics

> Display 100 polygons with side length 10, opacity.5, and random choices of colors, sides between 3 and 8, and integer coordinates up to 100.

```
Graphics[
    Table[
    Style[
    RegularPolygon[RandomInteger[100, 2], 10, n], RandomColor[], 
    Opacity[0.5]], 100, {n, 3, 8}]]
```

> this is the expected output. there is no error but something is wrong. plz help. thank you.
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating 600 polygons (6 groups of 100).You could make the sides random.

```
Graphics[
 Table[Style[
   RegularPolygon[RandomInteger[100, 2], 10, RandomInteger[{3, 8}]], 
   RandomColor[], Opacity[0.5]], 100]]
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this answer is based on a radius of 10 (as per your "SAMPLE EXPECTED OUTPUT"). But the text of the question mentioned a "side length 10" (see cvgmt answer for this approach).

Answer (score 0):

To keep the length of the side of the polygons to 10, we using `AnglePath`.

```
length = 10;
Graphics[
 Table[{EdgeForm[RandomColor[]], FaceForm[], 
   Polygon[AnglePath[ConstantArray[{length, 2 π/n}, n]]]}, {n, 3, 
   8}]]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[
 Table[With[{n = RandomInteger[{3, 8}], 
    position = RandomInteger[100, 2]}, {EdgeForm[White], Opacity[.5], 
    FaceForm[RandomColor[]], 
    Polygon[AnglePath[position, ConstantArray[{10, 2 π/n}, n]]]}],
   100], Background -> Black]
```

[image]